# Bootstrap table css not working with Vue.JS component

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, vue-component

I'm using bootstrap and Vue.js for a webapp. But I can't use bootstrap table css in a Vue component. When I write

```
<table>
  <tr class='active'>
    <td>place</td>
    <td>holder</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

outside Vue component the css works okay and the table is properly formatted. But when I use the same code within `<template>...</tenplate>` tag of the Vue component, the `active` style of bottstrap table css is not applied to the table row.

I am keeping the Vue component in a `.vue` file and compiling with webpack.

What's going wrong?

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle for it?

Comment: I would, but I'm not sure how would I get the *.vue file to compile in the jsfiddle.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Adding a `tbody` element to the table solved the problem. The code now reads

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr class='active'>
      <td>place</td>
      <td>holder</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The CSS is working properly now.

Comment: Awesome find! Thanks.

Comment: thank you! I had looked everywhere for this.

Answer (score 0):

I can see table working properly in Vue component. Following is code for table I am using:

```
 <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Email</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td>Moe</td>
        <td>mary@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@example.com</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Here is working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dgxavvgj/8/).